# Using not with both, either, neither: word choice when expressing negation of two options

Tags: grammaticality, negation, logic, double-negation, disjunction

In a sentence responding negatively to multiple statements or questions,
which of the following ways sounds best and has the least grammatical error?

1. He didn’t do both.
2. He didn’t do either.
3. He didn’t do neither.
4. He didn’t do none.
5. He did neither.
6. He did none.

If there are any grammatical issues with the sentence, please explain why.